# Coordinates from action-angle variables

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, action

I'm interested into getting the original coordinates, $q(t)$ and $p(t)$, from the action, $J=\oint p dq$, and angle, $w(t)=\frac{dH}{dJ}t+\beta$, variables for a 1-D, one particle system.

I know that one way to do it is by setting $\frac{d\bar{S}(J,q,t)}{dJ}=\beta$, where $\bar{S}(J,q,t)$ is the Hamilton's principal function with the change of variable from momentum to action, and solving for $q$.

I also know that a second kind generating function $F_2(q,J)$ can be obtained with:

$$F_2=\int_0^qp[E(J),x]dx$$
and therefore $w=\frac{dF_2}{dJ}$. Then $q$ and $p$ can be calculated by inverting $J[E(p,q)]$ and $w(J,q)$.

However, I'm specifically interested in writing $q(t)$ as a fourier series, which should be possible since we know that $\frac{dH}{dJ}$ is the fundamental frequency of the system. The [wikipedia article on action-angle coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action-angle_coordinates) suggests:

$$q(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\exp[2\pi i n w(t)]$$

But I have several problems with that. To begin with, this can't be an acceptable solution for the harmonic oscillator, furthermore there's no way to distinguish among different Hamiltonians that yield the same numerical frequencies. My guess is that this information should be enclosed in the coefficients that Wikipedia doesn't show. Nevertheless I've been looking around the web for such formulation and being completely unsuccessful at it. Any hint would be really appreciated.